# How to convert a string (describing arrays) into an array in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy

I have this string:

```
'[[57.7322273254, -58.8288497925, -54.460193634, 28.4842605591, -45.9620323181, -13.6266260147, -17.2981243134, -15.1332969666, -15.1287126541, -2.44765377045, -0.488036692142, -9.05566310883, -4.70651531219], [72.5999526978, -83.4902877808, -16.4493045807, 40.4356307983, -33.9553756714, -10.7394323349, -17.31067276, -15.6521835327, -25.1421508789, -13.1496963501, -4.11457395554, -14.9144859314, -5.76139545441]]'
```

I would like to convert this string into a numpy array of arrays

Comment: Use `ast` module...Ex:  `print(np.array(ast.literal_eval(s)))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import ast

print(ast.literal_eval('[[57.7322273254, -58.8288497925, -54.460193634, 28.4842605591, -45.9620323181, -13.6266260147, -17.2981243134, -15.1332969666, -15.1287126541, -2.44765377045, -0.488036692142, -9.05566310883, -4.70651531219], [72.5999526978, -83.4902877808, -16.4493045807, 40.4356307983, -33.9553756714, -10.7394323349, -17.31067276, -15.6521835327, -25.1421508789, -13.1496963501, -4.11457395554, -14.9144859314, -5.76139545441]]'))
```

This will make this string into a list.

You can cast it with `np.array` in order to have it as a numpy array.

Read here about [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or
>   node provided may only consist of the following Python literal
>   structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and
>   None.